# Save html extract to list of list Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I extract some data from a html page. My output is:

```
 0
0
0
0

131997
https://www.google.com.ar/
google.com.ar
 0
0
0
0

134930
https://www.a-a.com/
a-a.com
```

And I'm looking for this kind of output:

```
[['0','0','0','0','131997','https://www.google.com.ar/','google.com.ar'],['0','0','0','0','134930','https://www.a-a.com/','a-a.com']]
```

Here is my python code:

```
sitios = requests.get(url_sitios, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, passwd))
sitios2 = sitios.text
html = sitios2
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') #add the 'lxml' parser
for item in soup.find_all(['nombre', 'url', 'sitio_id', 'ultimas24hrs']):
   a = item.text + ','
   print a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This can be done in two lines using **List comprehensions**.

Now you have a string as:

```
string = '''
 0
0
0
0

131997
https://www.google.com.ar/
google.com.ar
 0
0
0
0

134930
https://www.a-a.com/
a-a.com'''

parts = [i for i in string.replace('\n',',').split(',') if i]
list_of_links = [parts[i:i+7] for i in range(0,len(parts),7)]
print(list_of_links)
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '131997', 'https://www.google.com.ar/', 'google.com.ar'], [' 0', '0', '0', '0', '134930', 'https://www.a-a.com/', 'a-a.com']]
```

Though it seems that this solution may be confusing to you but still it demonstrates that your problem can be solved in two lines as well.

Read [this](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) for details on what those above lines did.

Comment: Thanks bro! It is all I need!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
data = ['0','0','0','0','131997','https://www.google.com.ar/','google.com.ar','0','0','0','0','134930','https://www.a-a.com/','a-a.com']
a = []
count = 1
b = []
for item in data:
    if count == 7:
        a.append(b)
        count = 1
        b = []
    else:
        b.append(item)
        count = count + 1       
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
sitios = requests.get(url_sitios, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, passwd))
html = sitios.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') #add the 'lxml' parser
for item in soup.find_all(['nombre', 'url', 'sitio_id', 'ultimas24hrs']):
    a.append(item.text.split('\n'))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code only answers leave an impression that SO is a code-writing service.